# Inserting an auto generated value into a column with specific pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named `tblSample` which has columns `ID`, `PID` etc. I want to auto generate those two columns with a specific pattern.

For example:

```
  ID       PID
  ------   ------
  ABC001   PAB001
  ABC002   PAB002
  ABC003   PAB003
  ABC004   PAB004
    |        | 
    |        |
  ABC999   PAB999
```

As you can see, the pattern 'ABC' in `ID` and 'PAB' in `PID` is the same. How can I insert those records into a table automatically and the range between those three digits after 'ABC' or 'PAB' is 001-999?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to create table structure as below with one identity column as testID and other computed by using that column ID and PID:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpOne(testID INT IDENTITY (1,1), 
    ID AS ('ABC'+ (CASE WHEN len(testID) <=3 THEN CAST(RIGHT(0.001*testID, 3) AS VARCHAR) ELSE CAST(testID AS VARCHAR) END)), 
    Ename VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #tmpOne(Ename)
SELECT 'Test'

SELECT * FROM #tmpOne
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    CREATE TABLE #tt(ID VARCHAR(100),PID VARCHAR(100))
    GO
    INSERT INTO #tt(ID,PID)
    SELECT 'ABC'+RIGHT('000'+LTRIM(a.ID),3),'PAB'+RIGHT('000'+LTRIM(a.ID),3) FROM (
         SELECT ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(t.id,4,LEN(ID))> SUBSTRING(t.id,4,LEN(PID)) THEN SUBSTRING(t.id,4,LEN(ID)) ELSE SUBSTRING(t.id,4,LEN(PID)) END )+1,1) AS id
         FROM #tt AS t 
      )  AS a
    GO 999
```

Comment: Worked Thanks have a look at the answer Which @Suraz has given its quite Simple